# Find out who invited my bot the server using OAuth redirect uri

Tags: oauth-2.0, oauth, discord, discord.py

**Before someone marks this question as duplicate,**

- Yes I know audit log is a thing.
- No I won't use it because it requires permission.
- Yes it's easier to find out server owner
- No I need to know exactly who invited my bot

**I want to:**
Find out who invited my bot the server (user-guild id pair) using invite link redirection.
I read about the [OAuth2 API](https://discord.com/developers/docs/topics/oauth2) but didn't quite undertstand it due to my lack of background knowledge.
All I understand is that bot invite links can have redirect uri,
and some infos are transfered to it after authentication.
Is it possible to get user/guild id from this?

**I tried:**
Setting up http server using `python -m http.server`,
add my IP to redirect uri list in dev page & generate a invite link containing redirect to my IP.
But I didn't get redirected to my http server after inviting my bot using that link,
and nothing got printed on the http server console either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Things to note:
A. Don't reveal your client secret or your bot token for any purpose. If you do so, immediately regenerate them from the developer portal.
B. Code and token have different meanings in the answer below.
C. This is not for absolute beginners and you are expected to have a general understanding of web requests(specifically GET and POST requests). You might also need to host the site handling redirect URL.
D. This does not cover security issues in any shape, way or form.

1. In the bot tab of the developer portal, enable the `REQUIRES OAUTH2 CODE GRANT` option. This prevents the bot from joining a server unless step 4 is completed.
2. Then use the OAuth tab to generate an OAuth URL with identity and bot scopes. This is important to get user info in step 5.
3. When someone visits the URL, logs in, and selects a server, they are redirected to your redirect URL. This URL receives a single-use code as URL parameter ie the URL will be `<base_url>&code={code}<other stuff>`. It is up to you (and probably outside the scope of any SO answer; google is your friend here) to set up a web server and handle requests.
4. This code can then be used to get a token. [This link](https://discord.com/developers/docs/topics/oauth2#shared-resources) explains how to exchange code for token. It involves sending a post request with your application's client id and secret. Both are available from discord's developer portal. The response will also have information about the guild along with the token in fields "guilds" and "access_token" respectively.
5. Send a get request to `https://discord.com/api/v9/users/@me` with a header containing `Authorization: Bearer ${token}` where the token is obtained in step 4. The response is in JSON format and contains user data specified [here](https://discord.com/developers/docs/resources/user#user-object). Note: The link above is for the latest API version v9 which may change in future versions.

Edit:
It is possible to manually modify the URL to remove identity scope from URL. The bot would still join the server as long as you make a request to exchange the code for the token. In this case, the request to `/users/@me` would fail and you would have no access to the user object. It should be easy to make the bot leave the server if the request fails with the status code corresponding to unauthorized.